# Memory leak when using d3.js exit remove append to update diagram in realtime

Tags: d3.js, memory-leaks

I found memory leak when using exist().remove() and append() to dynamically update digram.
Could any one help to see if there's any wrong in my code or is this an issue with d3, I'm using version 3.x.

[image]

Here's the demo:
[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zakitel/edit)
[Devtool friendly](https://output.jsbin.com/zakitel#)

The main code to update diagram:

```
  var letters = d3.select('svg').selectAll('text').data(vowelsAndNums, function(d) {
    return d;
});

letters.exit().remove();

letters.attr('x', function(d,i) { return i*15; });

letters.enter().append('text')
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .attr('x', function(d,i) { return i*15; })
    .attr('y', 15);
```

Comment: most likely an artifact of the garbage collector, when it removes a particular item. Ever wondered why you never have "A" in the animation?